# Which reference to use in C# - ConvertIdType

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am a C# newbie and trying  to use the example in the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb799791(v%3Dexchg.140)

The problem is, it is asking for a reference and I can't seems to find it under
`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` or any of the sub references under that, eventhough article pointing it to be part of the Exchange webservices.

Error occurs under the below line. It says something about a missing directive.

```
ConvertIdType request = new ConvertIdType();
```

Below is my code:

```
using System,
using Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices;


ConvertIdType request = new ConvertIdType();//error on this line.
ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();// same error on this liine too

exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1); //this line works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you for your answers/pointers
```

UPDATE:: Thank you all for trying to answer my question. Sorry for not getting back earlier as I seem to have moved from that approach and continued without the requirement of this piece of code. It's been more than a year and I can't remember what was my ultimate goal in this.

Comment: Please post exception details or exact error message you see

Comment: @RoadRunner please post the error which is showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have posted both code for the EWS Managed API library and the EWS WSDL proxy. ConverItType is a class from the WSDL proxy unless you have a need to write code using the WSDL proxy i would suggest you stick to using the EWS Managed API which will make you life a lot easier. Your code for the EWS Managed API should look like

```
using System,
using Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data;

ExchangeService exchange= new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1@contoso.com", "password ");
exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com");;
```

then whatever you want to do eg if you want to convert and Id then use the sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/gg274397(v%3Dexchg.80)

Comment: Thank you, Glen. Thanks for the explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the type [ConvertIdType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/exchangewebservices.convertidtype?view=exchange-ews-proxy) should be under the namespace [ExchangeWebServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/exchangewebservices?view=exchange-ews-proxy) and not under `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Itay. Appreciates it.